# How to release project under public domain?

Tags: open-source, licensing

I'm currently working on project, which is going to demonstrate how widgets can be done with [Context Framework](http://www.contextfw.net). I will also publish the source code.

In this case I want to give users as much freedom as possible, so that they can freely copy-paste, modify and also relicense whatever code they reuse.

So, how do I mention that in the project? Are the some ready-made licences etc. that are suitable for this?

Comment: If you do not mean "public domain", please rephrase your question.  By releasing something to the public domain, you waive all your rights as an author and copyright holder.  That's what "public" and "domain" in "public domain" mean.  There will be no "license" beyond that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Creative Commons [CC0](http://creativecommons.org/about/cc0) license should suit your purposes.  It's public domain made as explicit and universal as possible.

> ### The Problem
>
> Dedicating works to the public domain is difficult if not impossible for those wanting to contribute their works for public use before applicable copyright or database protection terms expire. Few if any jurisdictions have a process for doing so easily and reliably. Laws vary from jurisdiction to jurisdiction as to what rights are automatically granted and how and when they expire or may be voluntarily relinquished. More challenging yet, many legal systems effectively prohibit any attempt by these owners to surrender rights automatically conferred by law, particularly moral rights, even when the author wishing to do so is well informed and resolute about doing so and contributing their work to the public domain.
>
> ### A Solution
>
> CC0 helps solve this problem by giving creators a way to waive all their copyright and related rights in their works to the fullest extent allowed by law. CC0 is a universal instrument that is not adapted to the laws of any particular legal jurisdiction, similar to many open source software licenses. And while no tool, not even CC0, can guarantee a complete relinquishment of all copyright and database rights in every jurisdiction, we believe it provides the best and most complete alternative for contributing a work to the public domain given the many complex and diverse copyright and database systems around the world...

Answer (score 3):

A ready-made license suitable for this is [Unlicense](http://unlicense.org/). You can add the unlicense text to a project to put it under public domain:

> The Unlicense is a template for [disclaiming copyright monopoly interest](http://cr.yp.to/publicdomain.html) in software you've written; in other words, it is a template for dedicating your software to the [public domain](http://stpeter.im/writings/essays/publicdomain.html). It combines a copyright waiver [patterned](http://ar.to/2010/01/dissecting-the-unlicense) after the very successful public domain SQLite project with the no-warranty statement from the widely-used MIT/X11 license...

Answer (score 2):

First of all, make sure that the [license of Context Framework](http://www.contextfw.net/license) is not binding you.

If yes, then you need to comply to it and release on the same or compatible license.

If not, just add a comment on top of your source files that says something like `/*the following code is released in public domain (where applicable) */`. People will ignore it anyway.